# Construct list using jinja2 for KubernetesPodOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, templates, arguments, jinja2, airflow

we have an application running in a pod I want to trigger with airflow. The application runs with a lot of entities and take a lot of time. The nature of our setup is that some of these might fail, and we want to be able to re-run using only one or a few of the enteties:

```
my_program # Run full application

my_program -e entity1 -e entity2 # Run application limited to entity1 and entety2.
```

My plan was to allow users to trigger the DAG again with a list of entities using the "Trigger with config" in the Airflow UI and have that limit the DAG using the `{{ dag_run.conf }}` options.

The problem I now face is that the `KubernetesPodOperator` expects a list of strings, and I do not understand how use jinja to construct a list where I before do not know its length.

This is what I tried, but then of course the jinja will not be templated. I understand how I can insert templated strings into the list, but now how I can do it when I do not know then length of the list in advance.

```
with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    description="Run my dag",
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 14),
    default_args=default_args,
) as dag:

    entities = """{%- for entity in dag_run.conf['entities'] -%} -p {{ entity }} {% endfor %}"""
    arguments = list(filter(None, ['my_program', *entities.split(' ')]))

    t1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="my_task_id",
        image="url_to_docker_image:latest",
        name="my_task_name",
        arguments=arguments,
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        env_vars={"AIRFLOW_RUN_ID": "{{ run_id }}"},
    )
```

Edit: Here is my second attempt using jinja and `render_template_as_native_obj=True,`

```
with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    description="Run my dag",
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 14),
    default_args=default_args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:


    arguments = """['my_program', {% if entities is defined %}
      {%- for entity in entities-%} '-p', '{{ entity }}', {% endfor %}
      {%- endif %}]
    """

    t1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="my_task_id",
        image="url_to_docker_image:latest",
        name="my_task_name",
        arguments=arguments, # type: ignore
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        env_vars={"AIRFLOW_RUN_ID": "{{ run_id }}"},
    )
```

But this seems to not be converted to a list properly:

`HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Pod in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Pod: v1.Pod.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Args: []string: decode slice: expect [ or n, but found \", error found in #10 byte of ...|{\"args\": \"['my_program|...`

Comment: Just to confirm: when you call the operator the arguments variable contains something like `["{%-", "for", "entity", "in", "dag_run.conf['entities']", "-%}", "-p" ....etc ]`

Comment: I am getting this error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected`, and i believe that is due to jinja trying to run templating on stings like in your example here above..

Answer (score 1):

The second approach worked with minor tweak. Of course the variable were not available in the example (which had been stripped down) and parameters were fetched from `dag_run.conf['entities']` instead of just `entities`.

The second problem was in what was valid input for jinja to convert to a python object, and I had to remove empty space at the end of the string as well as removing new line characters:

```
arguments = """['my_program', {% if dag_run.conf['entities'] is defined %}
  {%- for entity in dag_run.conf['entities']-%} '-p', '{{ entity }}', {% endfor %}
  {%- endif %}]
""".replace('\n','').strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right track with your second attempt, *but* the template in your arguments variable has an extra comma (',') at the end of the last entity.

```py
import jinja2
from jinja2.nativetypes import NativeEnvironment

env = NativeEnvironment()
template = env.from_string(arguments)
print (template.render(entities=range(5)) )
```

Outputs: `['my_program', '-p', '0', '-p', '1', '-p', '2', '-p', '3', '-p', '4', ]`

If you change your arguments variable to this:

```py
arguments = """
   ['my_program' {% if entities is defined %}
   {%- for entity in entities-%}, '-p', '{{ entity }}' {% endfor %}
   {%- endif %}]
   """
```

The output is now a string that can Jinja can convert to a python array:
`['my_program' , '-p', '0' , '-p', '1' , '-p', '2' , '-p', '3' , '-p', '4' ]`